# How to run a Java program (compiled to .exe) if it needs an older version of Java? (Windows)

Tags: java, windows, installation, launch

So, I have a program in a `.exe` file that needs Java 8 to run. I have Java 16 installed. I tried installing Java 8 with a Java installer that came bundled with the program but it is still run with Java 16. I have seen solutions that solve that problem but only with `.jar` files (using Java.exe CLI to launch the file with different Java path). I have lots of apps that run on newer Java versions so I can't uninstall Java 16.

The program is [here](http://polynom.eliz.com.ua/), it's all in Ukrainian but there is Google Translate (press the red button to download zip file, clear on VirusTotal except some [antivirus flagging a runtime packer](http://www.nictasoft.com/viruslib/malware/Packed.Win32.Dico.gen), `Інсталяція Polynom.txt` is the README)

**UPDATE 1:** in reply to a comment in an answer, the contents of the cmd file:

```
set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_291
set PATH="%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%PATH%"
D:\Distributive\Polynom\Polynom.exe
```

Comment: *...that needs Java 8 to run* Why so?

Comment: when I try to launch it, an error message pops up in a Java messagebox saying "Java is not supported. The current version is 16, the needed one is 8. Please update Java." [screenshot here](https://imgur.com/a/PoZiIUH)

Comment: Have you tried setting JAVA_HOME to point to Java 8 when running your application?

Comment: That has to be `set JAVA_HOME="C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_291"` because of spaces in the path. Your second `set` is fine

Comment: @g00se changed, still the same result

Comment: BUT ... that's *not* the version of Java 8 that is installed by the installer, so `JAVA_HOME` would be wrong

Comment: @g00se wdym, in the installer it says that it is installed there (default place)    [screenshot here](https://imgur.com/a/iXv1xfd)

Comment: I just downloaded. The jre inside the archive is jre-8u271-windows-x64.exe

Comment: @g00se yes and when i launch that java installer it says it is installed in the aforementioned location? i don't get you

Comment: *set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_291* is an entirely **different** version

Comment: @g00se hmm? so i should try to install java 8 to a different location and then choose **that**?

Comment: You should just simply use the correct version number for the one your installer installs

Answer (score 0):

So, you need to set JAVA_HOME (location where you installed JAVA 8, must have a directory `bin` and `lib`), and optionally add that to your PATH.

Open `CMD.EXE`

```
set JAVA_HOME=C:\path\to\Java
set PATH="%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%PATH%"
```

In the above file, `java.exe` is in `C:\path\to\Java\bin\java.exe`.

Then run the program from `CMD.EXE`

If that works, create a `CMD` file containing the above text - when you want to start the program, start the `CMD` file.

```
notepad c:\Users\jdoe\myprogram.bat
```

Copy the above two `set` lines into that file followed by the full path to the program you want to run. The file would look something like this:

```
set JAVA_HOME=C:\path\to\Java
set PATH="%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%PATH%"
C:\Users\jdoe\MyProgram.exe
```

**Tip**: If you want the icon of the program, create a shortcut of the CMD file

1. Right-click the CMD file, click *New > Shortcut*
2. Right-click the shortcut, click *Properties*, click *Change icon*
3. Navigate to the EXE file and select the icon you want

Comment: thanks, i'll try when i get home to my computer

Comment: sadly that didn't work, still the same error message

Comment: Could you post the contents of the `CMD` file ? Edit you question, add **UPDATE1:** and provide the contents of the file.

Comment: added command file